# C++ Random Number Generator with dynamic range

Tags: c++, random, range, srand

Hey I'm new a wanted to know how I can create a random number generator within a given range that can be changed as code is run( say range starts as 0 to 1000, but later can be modified to 430-600)

I have something like this (v is max and i is min)
Pls Help!

```
int range = (v - i )+ 1;
srand(time(0));
Guess = rand() % range+ i;
```

Comment: when you run your code, doesn't it do what you want? what's the result and what is the expecte result?

Comment: `srand(time(0));` if you are stuck using rand() make sure you call that 1 time only at the beginning of `main()`. reseeding in a loop could make it return the same numbers each time..

Comment: Start with writing a function that generates a random number in a given range, then change that function to use user-provided min/max

Comment: Use std::random, not rand.